# Javascript window.print() causes browser to hang

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that displays a list of "tickets". On each of these tickets, I'd like a "print" button which prints off just that ticket. I have this all working (cutting out the relevant info ready for printing, changing the colours to black on white etc) except that I would like it to automatically print the document rather than the user having to hit print (or Ctrl+P). When I call window.print() in javascript, it just hangs the browser (I've tried Chrome, Firefox and IE). If I manually press Ctrl+P or the print button, it works fine.

Has anyone ever come across this before, it seems pretty odd?

Comment: `window.print` works fine for me. Have you tried on another computer?

Comment: try reproducing in a jsfiddle

Comment: You may be calling print before the page is actually loaded. For a quick work around put the print call inside a timeout.

Comment: Thanks, Prusse. Your suggestion has fixed my issue. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), you could try the following to print if document is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  window.print();
});
```

Or as Pursse suggested

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){
       window.print();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is basically what I am doing now as a result of Prusse pointing me that way (except I'm using ExtJS rather than jQuery).